# form model binding and file upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I got an answer previously to my question about how to create edit/update details form in laravel, and the answer was utilizing Form::model(modelName). Nevertheless, the page which is updating is the same page handling the insertion. I have the following form opening:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'SomeController@basic','files' => true)) }}
```

how can I change this to use the form::model instead? I also have an upload of file in same page (profile pic).

Answer (score 5):

## Laravel 4 or 5 Form <-> Model binding

Maybe is a "bit" late for the original poster, but for those who search for a solution, this can be used as a later reference.

### The L4 solution is:

```
{{ Form::open($object, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => array('SomeController@update', $object->id),'files' => true)) }}
```

### For Laravel 5, you would use:

```
{!! Form::model($object, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' =>  ['ObjectsController@update', $object->id], 'files' => true]) !!}
```

Home this helps!

Comment: Don't forget to add 'method' => 'PATCH' in order to work

Comment: For Laravel 5: don't forgot to define your route like: Route::patch('some/basic' , 'SomeController@basic');

Comment: @3ehrang it is only necessary if you treat your routes individually. If you work with RESTFUL routes and route to the controller as a resource, than the patch route is not needed. `Route::resource('route/', 'MyController');`

Answer (score 4):

Form model binding can be done by declaring form open as

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('action' => 'SomeController@post', 'files'=> true)) }}
```

You pass the model to the view for example here $user is the model.

```
$user = User::find(1);
return View::make('editUser')->with(compact('user'));
```

For file upload, if the $user is isset you could display the image. Along with the upload button. When update is clicked you can check

```
if(Input::has('file'))
```

then move the file and upload the path in the database. May be there is a different solution for this.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: If you are using a model, typically you want to be using 'action' instead of 'url'.

Comment: That's what I would think would work ... but it's not.